# how to convert subdocument to array of field names?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In javascript, we have something like:

```
Object.keys({ A: 1, B: 2 })
> ["A", "B"]
```

In mongodb aggregation, is there something like that?

Comment: Use `$objectToArray` to convert the key-value pair to array of documents with `k` and `v`. Then use `$map` to get `k`. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nTSEbPoWQH0). And in your backend, get the keys with `/* result */[0].keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common and can be done with a double [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). In the first `$project` stage, convert the object to an array with [$objectToArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). Then in the second stage only `$project` the keys like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      obtoar: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      keys: "$obtoar.k",
      // values: "$obtoar.v"  //< Uncomment this line if you want the values too
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k4w1ngGiE4F)